# Dynamic character count of asp.net text box using JS/Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

> i have a textbox and i want dynamic character count of how many char
>   are left out of total max limit=500.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="300" Height="100">asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `val.value.length` to get a number of characters in the textbox/textarea.

```js
function countChar(val) {
  var len = val.value.length;
  if (len >= 500) {
    val.value = val.value.substring(0, 500);
  } else {
    $('.numbersofChart').text(500 - len);
  }
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="TextBox2" onkeyup="countChar(this)"></textarea>
<div class="numbersofChart"></div>
```

Comment: can u use DIV class instead of id ?

Comment: @DeepakJain Do you mean you want to select the div by a class and not id? if so check snippet

Comment: it's done i have use . for class thanks for the help !!

Comment: problem is coming when 1 char is left and u try to add another char..  i have updated the code

Comment: if (len >= 500) must be if (len > 500) - without the "=" check

Answer (score 1):

**solved your issue please test this code may help you better**

```
<h5 >Characters Left <span id="remaining">500</span></h5>

<input type="text" id="question_comment_body" name="question_comment_body" placeholder="Your Comment Here...">


<script type="text/javascript">
    function charCount() {
        var textEntered = document.getElementById('question_comment_body').value;
        var msg = document.getElementById('remaining');
        var counter = (500-(textEntered.length));
        msg.textContent = counter;
    }
    var el = document.getElementById('question_comment_body');
    el.addEventListener('keyup',charCount,false);
</script>
```